# How to do a prototype print of a business card

Tags: presentation-design, mockup

I'm a newbie in the freelancer world. I started creating logos and business cards and I show it to my customers. Well, I always face a problem how to present my work in a professional and a nice way. I need to know how to do a prototype print of a business card. Same as the image here, please tell me all the details I need to present it same as the image, I don't mean the work of the business card, I'm asking about the presentation itself.

[image]

Comment: While a presentation like that is somewhat 'cool' that's certainly not anything that a client needs to see and, I could argue, could cause more problems than it helps. Ideally you'd hand them an actual prototype. In other words, print the business card, cut it out, and hand it to the client for them to approve.

Comment: Thanks, but usually my clients are far away of me, so I communicate with them online and via email.

Comment: That's fine too, just make it a PDF. My point is that you want them to focus on the card itself. Make sure that is the key document being shown. If you want to spruce things up a bit by showing something like the example in addition, that'd be OK, though perhaps not necessary.

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it you have three choices. Do a presentation template using:

1. Photoshop/Illustrator
2. 3D Software
3. Photography

That's actually not so hard to do if you have some Photoshop/Illustrator or 3D Modeling/Rendering technical skills or if you have a good camera go analogical ... and then edit the images in order to place you content on them.

My suggestion would be to take some time and make a template for this kind of presentations ... check the web for tutorials on how to work with perspective and gradients in Photoshop and Illustrator.

Comment: There are actually lots of templates for these online, check out graphic river, as a good starting place. They are made in a 3d program rendered then have a smart object placed were the image should be, so all you have to do is edit the smart object in photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZevlMjqU3k ceck this out ;) Business Card Mockup Photoshop Tutorial and PSD

Comment: Hey, welcome to GD! Link-only answers don't do well here. Could you elaborate on what is explained in the video?