# How do I make a mockup PSD file from a pair of 3D renders?

Tags: 3d, overlay

I'm not sure if this falls more into the domain of graphic design or 3DCG so I figured I'll just ask the experts at image manipulations first. Basically, I made a 3D scene in Blender of a paper bag so a friend of mine can use in their design.
[image]

Problem is, my friend isn't familiar with 3D packages, so they asked me if I can export it into a PSD file that can be used in mockup, where they can slap their tidbits like logos and text on and the creases can be "overlaid" over their design, and I have no idea how to start with this.
Anyone got ideas how I can achieve this? Even what I should look up as a starting point would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Comment: At it's very simplest, a PSD template/mockup can be a simple layered file, with each element on its own layer. To be honest with you, I don't see why your friend can't just paste a logo image on top of the bag image, and maybe change the layer blending mode to overlay.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should render a couple of wanted views of the bag. Do that with care because it cannot be changed. You should also warp in Photoshop some dummy placeholder items on a different layers of the rendered images to show what areas actually should be covered. They will put proper art designs in place of your dummy images. You send something like this:

[image]

They send back something like this:

[image]

If this is your business you should want also high resolution, preferably freely scalable vector straight on the face versions of the designed items so that you can map them directly into the 3D model and print to actual bags. Be sure there's a written and signed agreement of what you should get, what is your right to use it or sell them forward and how much you must pay. Talks have a tendency to change when someone starts to think money. Prevent it beforehand with a written agreement.