# How do I add a glass effect to an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I need to add a glass effect to the picture so it looks like a real item. I tried to search but I could not find any good solutions.

I attached a photo of the real item and a design

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: See this [possibly related answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment/113824#113824)

Comment: The only hint of "it has glass surface" in image 1 is the not so clear reflection and maybe the not so bright refraction near the edge. Cannot you insert a transparent layer of your own portrait onto the image? Straight on the face view cannot have anything else. Try layer opacity say =10% for a start. One example  (the portrait photo is replaced by a clipart drawing)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAr6G.png

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I will try it today. @user287001 where did you get my portrait photo? lol

Comment: User Billy Kerr inserted a link to a case where he shows a working way to create a plausible reflection from so long distance that it presents nothing identifiable. Check it at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer: Reflections**

**A first approach**

The second image is an illustration. If we want to keep the Illustration look I would just add "flat" reflections. A shape with gradient transparency.

Different shapes will suggest different volumes.

[image]

**More complex reflections**

Take one photo suitable to be a reflection and deform it with some spherize effect, then put it over your image with some blending mode, like add.

[image]

Try to add a suitable background and integrate them with a shadow.

[image]

I dimed the circle a bit, to integrate it more to the muddy background.

[image]

**The Real deal**

The truth is that a real 3D program can make things more realistic. You can add real lights for reflections.

[image]

Add an image as a reflection

[image]

Add a background

[image]

Or change the shape of the 3D object.

[image]

Here is a simple setup. (A) Volume with glass material and a circle with your texture.

(B) an image as a light emission as a reflection

(C) A background.

[image]

Here is a close-up of the 3D object (a short cylinder with some rounded bevel) and the glass material.

As I want only reflections, not refractions, it is mostly a glossy and transparent material.

It is made in Blender.

[image]

---

An edition.

This is very lazy work. I should have edited the image for the reflection, making it more contrasted. Probably something like this. I only noticed it when I posted the images. (the same with the background)

[image]

<sub>https://pixabay.com/es/photos/ventana-mujer-por-la-ma%C3%B1ana-ni%C3%B1a-1148929/</sub>

---

Adding the background in the post, not in the render will give you more control to integrate the image with curves. (the floating shadow is not a shadow but a misalignment on the "glass 3D object with the object with your design... still a lazy work)

[image]

<sub>https://pixabay.com/es/photos/dormitorio-armario-cama-habitaci%C3%B3n-1872196/</sub>

Comment: Wow. You're so good at this.

Comment: I am very impressed with your answer. What 3d program did you use in the provided example?

Comment: Blender. It is free and great.

Comment: I thought Blender was the name of components :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -3):

The glass effect in an image by Photoshop is a built-in facility. Hence, you can add a photoshop glass filter from the **Filter>Filter Gallary>Distort>Glass.**

Comment: Photoshop's Glass filter will **not** do **anything** similar to the example image. The question isn't about the specific word "glass". It's about the desired appearance.